# Unknown reason of receiving empty audio stream using `wrtc` RTCAudioSink

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, sdp, rtcp

I work on POC project that should receive a remote audio stream and write it in to the file. I can subscribe on the data event using [wrtc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wrtc) RTCAudioSink but each recieved chunk is:

`ArrayBuffer { [Uint8Contents]: <00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... 220 more bytes>, byteLength: 320 }`.
And the result file is just a mp3 file of silence.
I'm not shure is that me doing something wrong or he library that I'm using couse this trouble.
Here is the backend code snippet:

```
const path = require('path');
const io = require('socket.io');
const {
  nonstandard: {
    RTCAudioSink,
    RTCVideoSink
  },
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCIceCandidate
} = require('wrtc');

const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
const { PassThrough } = require('stream');
const { StreamInput } = require('fluent-ffmpeg-multistream');

const clientHost = require('../config/connections').CLIENT_URL[process.env.NODE_ENV];

let audioSink;
let videoSink;
let audioStream;

const outputAudioPath = path.join(__dirname, 'out-audio.mp3');

const beforeOffer = () => {
  const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
    sdpSemantic: 'unified-plan'
  });

  return peerConnection;
};

module.exports = (http) => {
  const socketIO = io(http, {
    allowEIO3: true,
    cors: {
      origin: clientHost,
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      transport: ['websocket'],
      credentials: true
    }
  });

  socketIO.on('connection', (socket) => {
    let pc;

    socket.on('chatConnected', ({ roomId, senderId }) => {
      console.log({ roomId, senderId })
      socket.join(roomId);

      pc = beforeOffer();

      pc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
        if (!event.candidate) {
          return null;
        }

        socket.to(roomId).emit('newICECandidate', {
          roomId,
          senderId,
          candidate: event.candidate
        })
      };

      pc.ontrack = (event) => {
        if (event.track.kind !== 'audio') {
          return null;
        }

        audioStream = new PassThrough();
        audioSink = new RTCAudioSink(event.track);
        console.log('id ', event.track.id)
        console.log('label ', event.track.label)
        console.log('enabled ', event.track.enabled)
        console.log('muted ', event.track.muted)
        console.log('readyState', event.track.readyState)
        audioSink.addEventListener('data', ({ samples: { buffer } }) => {
          audioStream.write(Buffer.from(buffer));
        });

        ffmpeg()
          .addInput((new StreamInput(audioStream)).url)
          .addInputOptions([
            '-f s16le',
            '-ar 48k',
            '-ac 1',
          ])
          .on('start', () => {
            console.log('Start recording')
          })
          .on('end', () => {
            console.log('Stop recording')
          })
          .output(outputAudioPath)
          .run();
      };
    });

    // socket.on('participantConnected', (params) => {
    //   socket.to(params.roomId).emit('participantConnected', params);
    // });

    socket.on('participantDisconnected', (params) => {
      audioSink && audioSink.stop();
      audioSink && audioSink.removeEventListener('data');

      audioStream && audioStream.end();

      // socket.to(params.roomId).emit('participantDisconnected', params.senderId);
    });

    socket.on('message', (params) => {
      socket.to(params.roomId).emit('message', params);
    });

    socket.on('videoChatOffer', async (params) => {
      await pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(params.sdp));

      const answer = await pc.createAnswer();
      await pc.setLocalDescription(answer);

      socket.to(params.roomId).emit('videoChatAnswer', { ...params, sdp: pc.localDescription });
      // socket.to(params.roomId).emit('videoChatOffer', params);
    });

    // socket.on('videoChatAnswer', (params) => {
    //  socket.to(params.roomId).emit('videoChatAnswer', params);
    // });

    socket.on('newICECandidate', async (params) => {
      const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(params.candidate);

      await pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);

      // socket.to(params.roomId).emit('newICECandidate', params);
    });

    socket.on('cameraAction', (params) => {
      socket.to(params.roomId).emit('cameraAction', params);
    });

    socket.on('microphoneAction', (params) => {
      socket.to(params.roomId).emit('microphoneAction', params);
    });
  });
};
```

I tried to receive an audio stream with RTCAudioSink but all the chunks were empty.
I expect to receive an actual audio data from the client.

Comment: Can you hear the audio if you try to play it back during the live stream?

Comment: I had this exact issue and in my case the laptop BIOS had disabled the microphone.   I  confirmed this by going to a webcam/mic test site, and noting that it didn't work.  Once I pressed "Fn-F4", it worked as expected.

Comment: "pc.ontrack =" this is a definition, you need to add a listener that then uses pc.ontrack. Something like "pc.addEventListner('track',pc.ontrack). I also see that you run ffmpeg() right after adding the eventListener for 'data', that would not work you need to wait for onclose to run ffmpeg. At the point you run it, audioStream is still empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was getting an empty audio stream is completely silly. Somehow, the socket.to method was not working, and although I was receiving an offer, the answer was not being sent back to the remote peer. The peer was adding tracks, and the ontrack event was triggered, but until the answer is received by the remote peer, their audio stream will remain empty. After I fixed the sockets, it started working as expected. I was focused on the wrong thing and missed the obvious.